# Unknown characters fetching stock data from yahoo in csv format

Tags: python, csv

When I try to get historical stock data from yahoo finance in python I'm getting correct output in html, but in csv, it returns unknown characters

output of csv :

```
摁彪汣獯ⱥ汃獯ⱥ慄整䠬杩ⱨ潌ⱷ灏湥匬浹潢ⱬ潖畬敭㈊㄰ⴴ㐰㈭ⰵ䡙住ㄬ㐹㄰〶ⰰ㐳㐮ⰸ㔳〮㤹㤹ⰸ㐳㈮〹〰ⰱ㐳㐮ⰸ㔳〮㤲㤹ⰹ
```

Here is my code :

```
 def run():
   yahoo=Share('YHOO')
   file1=open("scripts/hisdata.csv","w")
   file1.write("Adj_close,Close,Date,High,Low,Open,Symbol,Volume\n")
   h= yahoo.get_historical('2014-04-25', '2014-04-29')
   h=h[0]
   a=h.values()
   a=','.join(a)
   a=a.split(',')
   vol=a[0]
   sym=a[1]
   adjcls=a[2]
   high=a[3]
   low = a[4]
   date = a[5]
   close = a[6]
   opn = a[7]
   file1.write(date+",")
   file1.write(sym+",")
   file1.write(vol+",")
   file1.write(adjcls+",")
   file1.write(high+",")
   file1.write(low+",")
   file1.write(close+",")
   file1.write(opn+",")
   print vol
   print date

   return (vol,adjcls,high,low,close,opn)
```

Comment: Your CSV sample shows as a bunch of Chinese characters for me. I don't know Chinese, so I can't tell whether they are invalid, but the characters as such look well-formed (for example, there is a matching close parenthesis soon after the opening parenthesis). Are you seeing something else? What do you expect to see?

Comment: The CSV module has a well-documented issue with Unicode; is your data in Unicode and, if so, which encoding?

Comment: im using unicode encoding.. this output is when opened in libre office. when opened in gedit, it shows correct data.

Comment: ... Still, what is "correct data"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following approach which makes use of Python's [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#module-csv) module to automatically create the correct format for your output:

```
from yahoo_finance import Share
import csv

def run():
    yahoo = Share('YHOO')

    with open("scripts/hisdata.csv", 'wb') as file1:
        csv_output = csv.writer(file1)

        # First write the header row
        heading = ['Adj_Close', 'Close', 'Date', 'High', 'Low', 'Open', 'Symbol', 'Volume']
        csv_output.writerow(heading)

        h = yahoo.get_historical('2014-04-25', '2014-04-29')[0]
        csv_output.writerow([h[value] for value in heading])

        print h['Volume']
        print h['Date']

        return ([h[value] for value in ['Volume', 'Adj_Close', 'High', 'Low', 'Open']])

print run()
```

The `yahoo_finance` module returns each entry as a dictionary, so it is easier and safer to extract each entry by name rather than trying to list the values.

For me this creates an `output.csv` file containing the following:

```
Adj_Close,Close,Date,High,Low,Open,Symbol,Volume
35.830002,35.830002,2014-04-29,35.889999,34.119999,34.369999,YHOO,28736000
```

And displays the following output:

```
28736000
2014-04-29
['28736000', '35.830002', '35.889999', '34.119999', '34.369999']
```

The data you are seeing is probably due to the method you are using to view the file, it appears to be decoding it incorrectly. The file should be opened as bytes e.g. ASCII. You should try loading it into a spreadsheet application, e.g. Excel.

For LibreOffice Calc try the following:

[image: LibraOffice import dialog]

To write all of the returned row data to the csv file, the following script could be used:

```
from yahoo_finance import Share
import csv

def run():
    yahoo = Share('YHOO')

    with open('scripts/hisdata.csv', 'wb') as file1:
        csv_output = csv.writer(file1)
        heading = ['Adj_Close', 'Close', 'Date', 'High', 'Low', 'Open', 'Symbol', 'Volume']
        csv_output.writerow(heading)

        for row in yahoo.get_historical('2014-04-25', '2014-04-29'):
            csv_output.writerow([row[value] for value in heading])

run()
```

Comment: when opening in gedit, im getting correct data. but viewing in libre office, im getting the Chinese characters

Comment: I think Libre Office allows you to specify the encoding to be used for the file when opening the csv file.

Comment: that worked..thanks a lot.. is there any way to get multiple date data in ? now im only able to get only one data

Comment: @ Martin Evans:  sir, can you please look this question to .. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34663064/how-to-get-multiple-data-and-display-it-in-html-table#)